# zf2 Doctrine joined Entities result is not in one object

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

When I run foreach then in first iteration I get table r row  object and in next iteration I get object of table ke row. Once table ke row iteration is done then in next iteration I get table r next row object then I get table ke row object.
This is my repo.

```
public function getPagedSelfReview(array $criteria)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
            $query ->select('r','ke')
                    ->leftJoin(
                        'User\Entity\KraEvaluation', 'ke', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.id = ke.kraReview and ke.evaluatedBy = :userId'
                )
                    ->andWhere('r.user = :userId')
                    ->setMaxResults($criteria['limit'])
                    ->setFirstResult($criteria['offset'])
                    ->setParameter('userId', $criteria['userId'])
                    ;           
        $paginator = new Paginator( $query );
        return $paginator;
    }
```

Example:

```
0 - table r first row
1 - table ke first row (based on join match with r first row's column)
2 - table ke Second row (based on join match with r first row's column)
3 - table r Second row
4 - table ke first row (based on join match with r second row's column)
5 - table ke Second row (based on join match with r second row's column)
```

etc

Need out put as

```
0 - array(
 0=>table r first row,
 1=> array(
   0=>table ke first row (based on join match with r first row's column),
   1=>table ke second row (based on join match with r first row's column)
  )
 )
1- array(
 0=>table r Second row,
 1=>array(
   0=>table ke first row (based on join match with r Second row's column),
   1=>table ke second row (based on join match with r Second row's column)
  )
 )
```

Comment: How does the generated SQL differ from what you expect? Just looking at `$this->createQueryBuilder('r','ke')` makes me think you will get a `SELECT r.* FROM r, ke LEFT JOIN ke WHERE ...`. The `FROM r,ke` would give you a implicit join. If this is correct, update to `$this->createQueryBuilder('r')` and `$query->select('r, ke')`.

Comment: @AlexP Sorry it was typo. I updated my question. I'm using the same as you suggested.